# How do I ensure the messages get to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, messages

I just got an iPhone 8 and I noticed if someone writes to me via their iPhone messages app, I only get it on my MacBook Pro, but I would not be able to get it on my iPhone.

I would I rectify this?

Comment: Are you signed in to the same accounts on both devices?  What account are they sending the message to and is that account also on your iPhone?

Comment: @fsb, yes I am signed in to my same account on both devices. They are sending the message via iMessages and as far as I can tell, its the same account. It has two variations on my name but when you go to Details its my same iPhone phone number, but it seems that one is for iPhone and the other one goes to my MacBook.